# How to append values of Overlapping buffers to points?

Tags: qgis, spatial-query

Kind of a hard to explain spatial problem here but here's the picture

[image]

The circles overlap but what I need to do is to get a spreadsheet with the intersecting point data that also has all the ids of the intersecting circles?

Ex: row 1 attribute data. Column with buffer ids 1,2,3,50,100

Or in another way, if 2 sites have 10 points that overlap:

- site A has 20 points total
- Site B has 15 points total

I need site A to have rank 1, and stay with 20 points

I need site B to have rank 2 and have all the overlapping points not being counted for, so in total it would only have 5 points

Please let me know if this is confusing

Answer (score 1):

To get the number of points in a polygon, follow the following tutorial:
http://www.qgistutorials.com/en/docs/points_in_polygon.html.

You can get the spreadsheet by ctrl-clicking the layer and choosing 'save as...' and select 'CSV'.

Comment: That just returns the point count normally. Does not solve the overlapping problem

Comment: Ah I see what you mean now. How about still adding the 'normal' count to the polygons, then ranking them 1 to n. Then iterating the polygons from 1 to n, counting the number of points in each polygon again and deleting the points in the polygon so that they will not be counted in the lower ranked polygons? I'm sorry to not have the time now to implement it but it could be a way forward...

Comment: If there were only those circles then yes it would be that simple, unfortunately those are just a small sample, my dataset has circles all around the uk, around 2000 circles